# Scala compiler expand types

Tags: scala, types, implicit, type-level-computation

Consider this code:

```
  trait TypeOr[E, F] {
    type T
  }

  implicit def noneq2[E, F](implicit ev: E =!= F): TypeOr[E, F] = new TypeOr[E, F] {
    type T = (E, F)
  }

  sealed trait Error[+E, +A]

  case class Err[E, A](e: Error[E, A]) {
    def combine[B, F](f: A => Error[F, B])(implicit ev: TypeOr[E, F]): Error[ev.T, B] = ???
  }
  val result = Err(null.asInstanceOf[Error[Int, Int]]).combine(_ => null.asInstanceOf[Error[String, String]])
```

So far so good. From the definitions above, I concluded, that the expanded type of the result is following:

```
  val itsType: Error[(Int, String), String] = result
```

But apparently it is not, since the compiler replies with:

```
 found   : returnerror.Comb.Error[returnerror.Comb.TypeOr[Int,String]#T,String]
 required: returnerror.Comb.Error[(Int, String),String]
  val itsType: Error[(Int, String), String] = result
```

Is it possible to find out the simplified - expanded type of the expression? I can't get this information from compiler, I tried to print the AST before the erasure phase, but the expanded type is still not there.

Comment: can you also provide code for `returnerror.TypeOr` ?

Comment: The compiler doesn't believe that `TypeOr` and `Tuple2` are equivalent. Should they be?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm specifically interested in seeing, what the compiler thinks those types are more than just solving this particular case. I tried to print compiler phases, but it doesn't print the expanded type in any phase.

Comment: @coubeatczech Try  to add `scalacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-Xprint-types", "-Xprint:typer")` to build.sbt.

Comment: Or you can enter expession in REPL and it will print type and value of this expression. Or you can use scala-reflect. `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._`
  `def printType[A: TypeTag](a: A) = println(typeOf[A])`

Comment: Or `println(typeOf[A].dealias)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, when you write that implicit `noneq2` has type `TypeOr[E, F]` you lost type refinement https://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/19/forget-refinement-aux.html . Correct is

```
implicit def noneq2[E, F](implicit ev: E =:!= F) = new TypeOr[E, F] {
  type T = (E, F)
}
```

or better with explicit type

```
implicit def noneq2[E, F](implicit ev: E =:!= F): TypeOr[E, F] { type T = (E, F) }  = new TypeOr[E, F] {
  type T = (E, F)
}
```

That's the reason why usually type `Aux` is introduced

```
object TypeOr {
  type Aux[E, F, T0] = TypeOr[E, F] { type T = T0 }

  implicit def noneq2[E, F](implicit ev: E =:!= F): Aux[E, F, (E, F)] = new TypeOr[E, F] {
    type T = (E, F)
  }
}
```

Secondly, automatically inferred type of `result` i.e.`Error[TypeOr[Int, String]#T, String]` (type projection `TypeOr[Int,String]#T` is a supertype of `(y.T forSome { val y: TypeOr[Int, String] })` and moreover of `x.T`) is too rough https://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/23/type-projection.html

It's better to write path-dependent type for `result`.

But

```
val x = implicitly[TypeOr[Int, String]]
val result: Error[x.T, String] =
  Err(null.asInstanceOf[Error[Int, Int]]).combine(_ => null.asInstanceOf[Error[String, String]])
```

doesn't compile.

The thing is that `implicitly` can damage type refinements https://typelevel.org/blog/2014/01/18/implicitly_existential.html

That's the reason why there exists macro `shapeless.the`.

```
val x = the[TypeOr[Int, String]]
val result: Error[x.T, String] = Err(null.asInstanceOf[Error[Int, Int]]).combine(_ => null.asInstanceOf[Error[String, String]])
val itsType: Error[(Int, String), String] = result
```

Alternatively, custom materializer can be defined

```
object TypeOr {
  //...
  def apply[E, F](implicit typeOr: TypeOr[E, F]): Aux[E, F, typeOr.T] = typeOr
}

val x = TypeOr[Int, String]
val result: Error[x.T, String] =
  Err(null.asInstanceOf[Error[Int, Int]]).combine(_ => null.asInstanceOf[Error[String, String]])
val itsType: Error[(Int, String), String] = result
```

Comment: if you define `def a: Unit = result` - which is obviously wrong type, how do you force the compiler the expanded type it expects?

Comment: @coubeatczech What do you mean by "expand type"? Actually you can check that `def a: Unit = result` compiles so it's correct type. In Scala value of any type can be tranformed to `Unit` type.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. So let's say it would be `def a: Int = result`. By expanded type I mean for `type T = String` to show `String` and not `T` - resolving the name of  the type until there is nothing more to resolve. In my example, the `#T` refers to some type and I want to resolve it.

Comment: @coubeatczech Try `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._`
  `def printType[A: TypeTag](a: A) = println(typeOf[A].dealias)`
`printType(result)`

Comment: i will get: `src/main/scala/returnerror/Error.scala:49: No TypeTag available for ev.T`

Comment: I will try to add a complete example to the question

Comment: @coubeatczech This means that `T` is not a type alias, it's just an abstract type.

Comment: Like `trait TypeOr[A, B] {
  type T 
}`.